# Pointers in class / freeing memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

That's probably pointers 101 ... but it's strangely hard (for me) to find an answer.

In the following example, will everything be automatically deleted properly or do I have to delete some manually ? That includes `Test t` too ...

My answer would be yes, everything's freed unless I use explicitly `new` but Im far from sure.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

class Obj
{
    public:
        Obj(int num) : m_num(num) {}

        int getNum() { return m_num; }

    private:
        int m_num;
};

class Test
{
    public:
        Test(Obj *po) : m_po(po) {}

        void print()
        {
            std::cout << m_po->getNum() << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        Obj *m_po;
};

class Test2
{
    public:
        Test2() {}

        void add(Obj &o)
        { m_vo.push_back(&o); }

        void print()
        {
            for (size_t i=0; i<m_vo.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << m_vo[i]->getNum() << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Obj*> m_vo;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Obj o1(1);
    Obj o2(2);
    Test t(&o1);
    t.print();

    Test2 t2;
    t2.add(o1);
    t2.add(o2);
    t2.print();

    //Would there be other uses of those objects t and t2 that could require a manual delete () ?

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: You might want to edit your code, you seem to have pasted parts of it twice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is accurate. You are not using `new` or `malloc` or equivalents. So you are not responsible for deallocating anything.

Comment: Thanks. That's reassuring. Again, if I don't use new (or malloc), I never EVER have to worry about memory leaks caused by pointers ? I used EVER this time for the ultimate confirmation.

Comment: That is correct. Think of it like this: You can only call delete or free on something that was created with new or malloc. So, if you never called new or malloc, you have nothing on which you can call delete and free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everything will be destroyed and deallocated correctly, as all objects in there have *automatic storage duration.* Only object with *dynamic storage duration* (those created by `new` or `new[]`) need to be deallocated manually (by `delete` or `delete[]`, respectively).